# how to get appCheck token in getStaticProps next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-app-check

I need to pass the appCheck token to my request in getStaticProps but when I use getToken( method it throws the error below:
`AppCheck is being used before activate() is called for FirebaseApp [DEFAULT]`
Is there any way to use appCheck token in serve Side Rendering?

firebase.js:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
  appCheck.activate(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_CHECK_SITE_KEY, true);
    });
}
```

index.js:

````
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
let token
appCheck
    .getToken(/* forceRefresh= */ false)
    .then(async (rs) => {
      token = rs.token;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  const places = await getAllPlaces(token);

  return { props: { places }, revalidate: 60 };
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue in this post that may be helpful: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35689.

Currently, I don't think using App Check with Server Side Rendering is possible, likely because App Check interacts with the client browser and not the server.

That's only a theory, but picking up from the docs, I think App Check requires at least some access to the client.

> The updated client app will begin sending App Check tokens along with every request it makes to Firebase...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider?hl=en